# How to set the screen to not rotate (android)?

Tags: android, screen, orientation

I created an android app which requires the screen to be only in portrait mode.
While typing the IDE showed only this for orientation.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

The above code actually **worked** in the emulator. But when I checked it on a physical device. The app is rotating to landscape even with that code. How do I solve this?

I checked for screenOrientation is not working.
*Thanks in advance*

Comment: use    android:screenOrientation="portrait" for activity in manifest

Comment: screenOrientation is also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your manifest **android:screenOrientation="portrait"**

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivityKt"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

**For Example :**

[image]